# TYPO3 / bootstrap package trouble in update wizard

Tags: doctrine, typo3, typo3-10.x

I have a TYPO3 Error in the update wizard.
Seems to say that there is some trouble with the bootstrap package

Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliStatement::fetchOne()
in ../typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Classes/Updates/AccordionMediaOrientUpdate.php line 99
)
)
)
->execute();
return (bool) $result->fetchOne();
}

TYPO3 10.4.32 / bootstrap package 12.4

Some help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are on an older Doctrine version, that does not know the fetchOne() method yet. Try to do a composer update to get the latest matching Doctrine for your TYPO3 installation.

Comment: thank you, I haven't used the composer yet, made a try - but, for example, in this installation there is an extensions that doesn't support composer mode. However, does it mean that i have to use a composer based installtion to fix this problem?

Comment: I guess , that's the reason why the package is the old one, since it might be the one shipped with the non-composer TYPO3 packages. Now the bootstrap package expects something new, which can't be provided automagically without composer. Still You can try to update the Doctrine packages manually. They should be located in the vendor folder of your TYPO3 installation.